# for loop in if nested for loop in r

Tags: r

My loop is not working from the third `else if`.

I want that if that statement is true that `Cumu_excess_se2` at that position is equal `Excess_se` at that position and from there to the end that `Cumu_excess_se(t) =Cumu_excess(t-1) + Excess_se(t)`

My vectors are:

- `Q` is solar electricity available hourly
- `Excess_se` is the excess to store per hour
- `Cumu_excess_se2` is the vector sum of the excess

The loop:

```
for (j in 1:length(Cumu_excess_se)) {
    Cumu_excess_se[j] = sum(Excess_se[1:j])

    se.to.h <- vector("numeric", length(Excess_se))
    for (t in 1:length(se.to.h)) {
        if (Q[t] > maxse) {
            se.to.h[t] = maxse
        } else if ((Q[t] < maxse) & (Cumu_excess_se2[t] == 0)) {
            se.to.h[t] = Q[t]
        } else if ((Q[t] < maxse) & (Cumu_excess_se2[t] >= maxse)) {
            (se.to.h[t] = maxse) & (Cumu_excess_se2[t] = Cumu_excess_se2[t - 1] - (maxse - Q[t]))
        } else if ((Q[t] < maxse) & (Cumu_excess_se2[t] < maxse) & (Cumu_excess_se2[t] > 0)) {
            (se.to.h[t] = Cumu_excess_se2[t]) & (Cumu_excess_se2[t + 1] = Excess_se[t + 1])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll be hard for users to answer your question unless you make it reproducable. Here are some tips on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you clean up the formatting of your loops? I don't want to edit them in case I get the intention wrong, but I can't follow what they're all doing at the moment. Making your problem minimal may help (see the post @jruf003 links to)

Comment: @Phil Done: copy to clipboard and run `formatR::tidy_source()`. Really handy.

Comment: I think if you describe goal in words we can help better - for loops may not be necessary at all. I'm very confused by the line `(se.to.h[t] = maxse) & (Cumu_excess_se2[t] = Cumu_excess_se2[t - 1] - (maxse - Q[t]))` - what is the `&` supposed to be doing?

Comment: I have a vector Q which is the energy that I can produce per hour, from there I need to deliver a maxse value per hour if possible to the vector [se.to.h] and the rest needs to be store in a vector [cumu_excess].   This cumu_excess is going to be used later when Q < maxse and then  [cumu_excess] has to be updated.    My vector Q looks like that repeated 365 Q(0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 5064.198, 30127.683, 44032.768, 56049.508, 59997.865, 58710.358, 50813.643, 36221.887,  9441.724, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000)